# Create an array from object data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this type of data in an object in my project.

```
{
    "name": "Travel",
    "map": [
        {
            "name": "Montreal",
            "lat": "45.498649",
            "lng": "-73.492729"
        },
        {
            "name": "Brossard",
            "lat": "45.466667",
            "lng": "-73.450000"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I create this type of structure code to show my Google Map ?

```
var locations = [
  {
    name: "Montreal",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(45.498649, -73.492729)
  },
  {
    name: "Brossard",
    latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(45.466667, -73.450000)
  }
];
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more simple if you use 'forEach':

```
json.map.forEach(function(val){
    locations.push({
        name: val.name, 
        latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(val.lat, val.lng)
    });
});
```

Comment: It do not conserves my initial wanted structure with the `new google.maps.LatLng` part.

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
for (i = 0; i < dmap.length; i++) {
    locations.push({name: dmap[i].name, lat: dmap[i].lat,lng:dmap[i].lng});
}
```

Another way is doing it with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
dmap.map(function(item){
    return {name: item.name, lat: item.lat, lng:item.lng};
});
```

[`JSFIDDLE Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/v55k04pg/).

**Since You Editted** this is the relevant code:

```
for (i = 0; i < dmap.length; i++) {
    locations.push({name: val.name, 
        latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(val.lat, val.lng)
    });
}
```

Or

```
dmap.map(function(item){
    return {name: val.name, 
        latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(val.lat, val.lng)
    };
});
```

Comment: Good but how can I include the `new google.maps.LatLng` part ?

Comment: thats an external class that probally comes with adding the google maps js file.

Comment: No I really need this part, if not, it will not work.